# Regarding installation of angular using npm

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, npm-install

I am trying to install angular using command
`npm install -g @angular/cli`
I have also tried the commands like
`npm install -g angular-cli`
and
`sudo npm install -g angular-cli`
but none of it is working at all and at various steps its showing various errors
But the most recent one is
**EExist**
and file already exist which it does not as the following proves it :
but when i type `ng -v` or `ng --version`
it says command not found !
What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that worked for me :
Run `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
Then Run : `alias ng="/Users/[local]/.npm-global/bin/ng"`
Then : `ng version`
and done !!!!